# Acquire Azure Active Directory resource access token from powershell for current user?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to acquire an Azure Active Directory based token for a certain Azure Resource (in my case Time Series Insights) using PowerShell? Not for some service principle but for the current user. In .NET (c#) that's by now very easily doable be using [Managed Service Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity#obtaining-tokens-for-azure-resources):

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;

var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string token = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://api.timeseries.azure.com/");
```

So is this something that would also be doable in PowerShell? Any example I have seen so far always uses either Service Principles or just gives me tokens for the Azure management APIs for the current user.

Comment: Are you trying to get the access token for the current user, for a specific Azure RM resource within PowerShell?

Comment: for the current user. In my case I need the token for HTTP requests against Time series insights, but the same should work e.g. for the Microsoft Graph API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PowerShell script runs on a machine that is joined to the Active Directory on premises domain, the machine is connected to the enterprise network, and the user who runs the script is a domain user synchronized to Azure Active Directory, then you can use an override of ADAL [AcquireTokenAsync](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-Integrated-authentication-on-Windows-(Kerberos)) which uses integrated Windows authentication.

This PowerShell example acquires a token for the current user to call Graph:

```
add-type -path "\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.3.13.4\lib\net45\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"
$clientId = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2"
$resourceAppIdURI = "https://graph.windows.net"
$UserCredential = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential" -ArgumentList "user@contoso.com"
$authority = "https://login.windows.net/TENANT.onmicrosoft.com" 
$authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority,$false
$authResult = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions]::AcquireTokenAsync($authContext,$resourceAppIdURI,$clientId,$UserCredential).result
```

In the the example, the client ID is the well-known PowerShell GUID, and the resource is AAD Graph. If you need to call another API (i.e. Time Series Insights) you will need to register a new application (a native application) that represents the script (you need to specify the GUID of this new application in the script, $clientId variable) and give it delegated permissions to call the API. Also make sure to specify your tenant name in the $authority variable, and the API GUID or URI in the $resourceAppIdURI variable.

Comment: my machine is Azure Active Directory joined. Not sure if it's because of that, but the script runs without an error for my but $authresult is null is the end. I tried it with the graph.windows.net resource for now and changed TENANT to my org

Comment: If you pass your UPN into $UserCredential (like the doc I linked says), does it make any difference? Like this: $UserCredential = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential" -ArgumentList "user@contoso.com"